# Deleting a linked list

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to delete complete linked list using free() function but it is not working. Why?

```
void delete(Node** head_ref)
     {
         free(*head_ref);
         return;
     }

 delete(&head);
```

Comment: You are only deleting the head node. What about the rest?

Comment: What does, "It is not working" mean? Does it crash? Or is it leaving memory allocated? Or perhaps it's causing some other problem? "It is not working" is not a helpful description of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just deleting the head node of the list. Rest of the nodes are still there. There are two ways to do what you want to do.

```
void delete(Node** head_ref)
 {
     if(head_ref==NULL){
          return;
     }
     delete(head_ref->next);
     free(*head_ref);
     return;
 }

 delete(&head);
```

and if you want to do it without recursion

```
void delete(Node** head_ref)
 {
     Node** temp_head = head_ref;
     while(temp_head!=NULL){
         temp_head = head_ref;
         head_ref = head_ref->next;
         free(*temp_head);
         temp_head = head_ref;
     }
     return;
 }

 delete(&head);
```

PS I haven't written code in C for a long time so if there is any error, let me know.